# The correct way to link a DependencyProperty to a ViewModel Property?

Tags: vb.net, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have a View and a ViewModel which I have cut the relevant extracts from and posted below. Binding from visual elements in my View to my ViewModel is working fine. What I need to do is bind a Dependency Property to my ViewModel Property and keep it updated on changes. I have achieved this by referencing the ViewModel each time the Dependency Property is updated. This however doesn't feel like the correct way, can anyone please advise on a better solution?

**My View:**

```
   Public Shared FloorIDProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FloorID",
    GetType(String), GetType(FloorView), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing))

   Public Property FloorID As String
        Get
            Return GetValue(FloorIDProperty)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            SetValue(FloorIDProperty, value)

            Dim dc As FloorViewModel = TryCast(Me.DataContext, FloorViewModel)
            If dc IsNot Nothing Then
                dc.FloorID = value
            End If
     
        End Set
    End Property
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
  Private _floorID As String
    Public Property FloorID As String
        Get
            Return _floorID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _floorID = value
            OnPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: The usual way to do this is with a binding in your xaml.  You should also delete the code that manually updates back to the viewmodel when the property changes, the binding machinery should do this for you.

Comment: I fully understand how to bind from the View to the View Model for a UI Element, my question here is how do I do the same for a dependency property not used in the UI?

Comment: In that case, I'd say either continue with what you're doing, or set up a binding in code.  I'm curious, though, what use you would get out of a dependency property that isn't used in the UI.

Comment: I am binding dependency properties between my views as I have multiple views and multiple view models. I also have singleton view models for some views and other views of the same type bound in an observable collection, each with its own view model. So I am using the dependency properties to share common values. I could achieve this by messaging between my view models but I feel that this would be a less elegant solution.